# 10/3 Romex to my kitchen stove

Tags: wiring, kitchens

I know the answer to this, I am SOL, but I thought I would ask it anyway.

In my kitchen I have a built in oven in a cabinet with a microwave above it.   Looking at my breaker I can see an orange 10/3 romex with a 30 amp / 240 v double breaker.  And a yellow 12/2 to the dedicated to the microwave with a 20 amp breaker.

I am redoing my kitchen and I want to replace the two separate units with a paired oven / microwave.   Of course all the modern built in oven combos are 40 amps - and I have 10 gauge wire.

Do I have any options other than running a new 8 gauge wire?

////

Something else interesting - the breaker / wiring to my cooktop is also 240 / 30 amp at the box, but is only wired as 110 under the cabinet.   I am assuming the third wire is capped in the outlet?   I need to check that to be sure, Is that safe?

Comment: Cooktop needing 240v but wired as 120v is weird.  As in the clock will work, but the stove would only have half power.  Pictures of that connection will help.  I think you know the answer about using 10 gauge on 40 amps.

Comment: If you're redoing your kitchen, is there any chance of redoing wiring?

Comment: Check to see if the microwave of the new combo unit as a separate 120V plug that just plugs into an outlet mounted on the oven and protecred by a mini-breaker. You might be able to plug the microwave into your 12/2 and the oven into th 10/3.  The oven nameplate should show the load for the oven and the microwave separately.

Comment: I was reading the specifications on the oven unit - and yes, the microwave (110) does plug into an outlet on the oven itself.   I wonder….  I am going to see what the amp rating for the oven is “stand alone”.  

That might be the answer.

Comment: As for the cooktop - it is gas and is only “using” 110v, but it is 220v at the breaker.   When I have time I will pull the outlet cover and see what they are doing with the second hot wire.  

But it would seem smarter to me not to run a dead end hot wire to an outlet box.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you gave actual details on your intended appliances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably allowing for a potential electric cooktop with the 10Ga wire, but incorrect to have it on a 30A breaker if there's a normal 15-20A 120V NEMA 5 outlet attached.

A 15 or 20A double breaker could be wired as an MWBC to feed each half of the outlet separately and be correct, though. They might have done that, but with the wrong breaker size for feeding that end-point.

Comment: There's probably  a mini circuit breaker installed for the  outlet attched. That's what mine has. It's between the oven and the microwave in the vent area.

Answer (score -1):

30A is perfectly reasonable for a gas cooktop + electric oven (probably the best of both worlds, induction notwithstanding, because it avoids the added humidity in a gas oven, which can affect recipes).

If your oven is demanding 40A, I would consider a different one.

Lastly, if this is you taking the two 20A ovens and adding 20+20 and inferring a 40A requirement, carefully read NEC 220.55, which provides a favorable derate for cooktops and/or ovens.

Comment: It sounds like the OP has a counter location with a cooktop only, and a built-in cabinet spot for an oven and a microwave. Switching to a combo cooktop/oven stove would require remodeling their kitchen.

Comment: @nobody I didn't say anything about a combo.  That's called a "range" and I would have said range.  In fact I said cooktop.  And from context you can tell I'm suggesting changing to a less dumb oven.